# css i want to apply style to everything not just body

Tags: css, styles

i want to apply my style to everything not just body

style.css :

```
body {
    background-color: #3F3F46;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: url('https://lelkasa.github.io/cursourcustom.png'), auto;
}
```

Comment: then use universal selector `*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `body` with `html`

```
html {
    background-color: #3F3F46;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: url('https://lelkasa.github.io/cursourcustom.png'), auto;
}
```

You can also use `*` because the `*` selector selects all elements.

```
* {
    background-color: #3F3F46;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: url('https://lelkasa.github.io/cursourcustom.png'), auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS into:

```css
html {
    background-color: #3F3F46;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: url('https://lelkasa.github.io/cursourcustom.png'), auto;
}
```